# Disable setJavaScriptEnabled when using leaflet on android

Tags: java, android, leaflet

One of the activities in my app has a map on it.

I'm using `Leaflet` as my map and in order to use it I used `WebView`.

Then, In my code I use:

```
String Map_HTML = "<html>\n" +
        "<head>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n" +
        "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n" +

       TONS OF HTML HERE

        "    color: 'red',\n" +
        "    fillColor: '#8275FE',\n" +
        "    fillOpacity: 0.3,\n" +
        "    weight: '0'\n" +
        "}).addTo(mymap);\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "var popup = L.popup();\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</script>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</body>\n" +
        "</html>";

WebView MapView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb_map);
WebSettings webSettings = MapView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
MapView.loadData(Map_HTML, "text/html", null);
```

In the end of the script I use `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` which gives a warning saying:

```
Using setJavaScriptEnabled can introduce XSS vulnerabilities into your application, review carefully.
```

From what I read, some people got messages from `play store` that asks them to update the app so it won't have this.

Since my goal to publish the app soon, I was wondering if there is an option to run it without this line?

I tried to remove it but then it just didn't show anything in the WebView.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
```

before

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview)

Comment: Isn't it just a "hiding the problem solution"?

Comment: not useful at all

Comment: @Ben no it's not hiding the problem - the warning tells you to "review carefully". if you have reviewed carefully already, then feel free to suppress the warning.